# Создать двоичный файл, куда записать n целых чисел. Из файла создать массив, элементы которого являются простыми числами

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы, простые-числа

Нужна помощь со второй частью задачи. Массив я сделал, но нужно чтобы элементы которые являются простыми числами должны располагаться после максимального значения файла.
Не могу додуматься как сделать.

Вот прога:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>



using namespace std;
int main()
{
ofstream out("Q:\\C++\\massiv.txt");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
srand(time(NULL));
const int n = 10;
int m[n],i=0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
m[i] = rand() % 21 - 10;
out << m[i] << " ";

}
out << endl;

ifstream fin("Q:\\C++\\massiv.txt");
int m1[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i);
{
fin >> m[i];
}
cout << "Массив = ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
cout << m[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
system("pause");
fin.close();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Вы создали не бинарный а текстовый файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, я бы делал вашу задачу примерно так - учитывая, что требуется *бинарный* файл, а не текстовый, как сделали вы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

bool is_prime(unsigned int k)
{
    if (k < 2 ||k%2 == 0) return false;
    for(unsigned int j = 3; j*j <= k; ++j)
        if (k%j == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream out("massiv.txt",ios::binary);
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int n = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        unsigned int x = rand() % 121 + 10;
        out.write((char*)&x,sizeof(x));

    }
    out.close();


    ifstream fin("massiv.txt",ios::binary);
    unsigned int m[n];
    unsigned int m_size = 0;
    unsigned int k;
    while(fin.read((char*)&k,sizeof(k)))
    {
        if (is_prime(k)) m[m_size++] = k;
    }

    cout << "Массив = ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        cout << m[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    fin.close();
}
```

Хотя на самом деле я бы работал с вектором. Да, и числа я брал беззнаковые, чтобы иметь дело только с натуральными числами (все же по определению простое число - это **число натуральное**, которое...), и не думать - скажем, `-5` - это простое или нет?...

Comment: Спасибо большое!